# jQuery UI Datepicker - Disable current date but NOT the highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I have the following code which disables the current date by setting minDate to current date + 1:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

        $("#minDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "none",
            minDate: tomorrow,
            dateFormat: "DD dd-mm-yy",
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                minDateChange;
            },
            inputOffsetX: 5,
        });
```

[image: Datepicker that has the current date disabled]

The problem is that I want to disable the current date, but still keep it highlighted (Blue border around the date) in the calendar.

Is there a native way to do this using the datepicker or do I have to create a highlight script myself?

Comment: Isn't the highlighted date the default chosen? If so, it can't be chosen and out of defined range at the same time.

Comment: First, just disable current date by, minDate: "+1D", and then override its style as:  .ui-datepicker-today span{background: #036!important; something else....} to anything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datepicker has a class on todays date called "ui-datepicker-today", so I simply added a class to that:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-today span").addClass("ui-state-hover")
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to set today and tomorrow as a variable. just set `minDate: 1`

Comment: that is an interesting comment but doesn't answer how to disable the current date while still highlighting it.