# minDate:0 in Jquery DatePicker also disable today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Sorry for posting this simple question. Application is going to be deployed soon, and recently a bug came, but i am not able to figure out why it is comming.

Created A JS_BIN this is the link

http://jsbin.com/razufavuru/1/edit?html,js,output

Error is minDate: 0 is disabling today's date also while i want to disable only past dates.

This is jquery code:

```
$("#leaveEndDate").datepicker(
    {
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay : disablePublicHolidaysAndWeekends,
        minDate : dateToday,
        onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
            var firstDate = $("#leaveStartDate").datepicker('getDate');
            var selDate = null;
            selDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var lastDate = selDate;

            if (lastDate < firstDate) {
                $("#leaveEndDate").val('');
                $("#endDateError").html(
                        "End Date must be greater than Start Date");
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            } else {
                $("#endDateError").html("");
                calculateDays(firstDate, lastDate);
            }

        }
    });
```

Disable Holiday and Weekends Method is

```
function disablePublicHolidaysAndWeekends(date) {
 var month = date.getMonth();
 var day = date.getDate();
 var year = date.getFullYear();
if(day < 10 && day > 0){
    day = '0'+day;
}
var getdate = year+ '/' + '0' +(month + 1) + '/' + day;
for (var i = 0; i < publicHolidayDates.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray( getdate ,publicHolidayDates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
        return [ false ];
    }
}

var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [ true ];
```

}

this is the img

[image]

public holidays are comming from database.

It confuse me  lot when this code for another datapicker works.

```
$("#targetDate").datepicker({
   beforeShowDay : $.datepicker.noWeekends,
   minDate : 0
 });
```

Here it do not disable today date.
this is the img

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059192/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-current-date-but-not-the-highlight

Comment: Nope i don't want to disable current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Datepicker value [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) expect value of type

> Type: Date or Number or String

Try `minDate: new Date()` instead, or `minDate: '0'`

UPDATE:

What causes your issue is your custom function:

```
function disablePublicHolidaysAndWeekends(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    if(day < 10 && day > 0){
        day = '0'+day;
    }
  if(month < 9 && month > 0){ //added control over month, as you would have got errors for month=10, 11, 12 in the below variable getdate
     month = '0' +(month + 1);
  }
  else{
    month += 1;
  }
    var getdate = year+ '/' + month + '/' + day;
    for (var i = 0; i < publicHolidayDates.length; i++) {
        //removed "|| new Date() > date"
        if ($.inArray( getdate ,publicHolidayDates) !== -1 ) {
            return [ false ];
        }
    }

    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [ true ];
}
```

Read this about [Date comparison in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)
[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qw57xes6/)

Comment: Check answer and fiddle